# Error in `[.data.frame`(x, c(key.ord, criteria)) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r

I am trying to create a Manhattan plot for the following results:

```
  CHR       SNP     BP A1 TEST NMISS
1   1 rs3131972 742584  A  ADD    80
4   1 rs1048488 750775  C  ADD    80
    BETA    SE    L95   U95    STAT
1 -2.234 2.977 -8.068 3.601 -0.7503
4 -2.234 2.977 -8.068 3.601 -0.7503
       P
1 0.4554
4 0.4554
```

I am using the code :

```
manhattan(subset(GWASresults, CHR == 1), xlim = c(1,4))
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, c(key.ord, criteria)) :    undefined columns selected.
```

what have I done wrong? I am very new to coding and R.

Comment: Where does the `manhattan()` function come from? That's not a function in base R. I'm guessing that function assumes that your data.frame has certain column names but your data doesn't match those expectations.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I am very new to coding and I'm just trying to follow instructions that my professor has given me. what would you suggest to do to plot a Manhattan plot.

Comment: If you can't tell us where the function is coming from, then there's not much we can do to help you. I suggest you ask your professor.

Comment: @MrFlick the function is from qqman

Answer (score 0):

Why have you given the limit `xlim = c(1,4)`?
There's some problem with the BP value in your data.

I am getting the plot from the original data

```
manhattan(subset(gwasResults, CHR == 1), xlim=c(1,4))
```

[image]

The x axis in the plot represents the BP value. If you want to have av limit for x, it should be beyond the maximum value of BP, in your data set.

```
manhattan(subset(gwasResults, CHR == 1))
```

[image]

With your data:

```
manhattan(subset(gwasResults, CHR == 1), xlim=c(1, 900000))
```

[image]